# Display element next to another from different parts of the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have two forms, one larger and one smaller. I would like to display the smaller form next to a specific input of the larger form. It's not valid html to embed one form within another in the DOM, but is there a way to display one form over / inside another form next to a specific input using CSS or JS?

```html
<!-- Main Form -->
<form action="action1" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    Job Title <input type="text" name="job_title" value="">
    Cell Number <input type="tel" name="mobile" value=""> <!-- SMALLER FORM SHOULD DISPLAY NEXT TO CELL # INPUT -->
    Favorite Sport <input type="text" name="favorite_sport" value="">
    Hobbies <input type="text" name="hobbies" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<!-- Smaller form loaded via js -->
<form id="optin_js_loaded_form"></form>

<!-- js -->
<script src="external_js_library.js"></script>
<script>
    // js code to load form into #optin_js_loaded_form using external_js_library.js
</script>
```

**NOTES**

- The forms need to be separate because the smaller form is created via an external js library from a marketing service.
- I know I could make the data from the larger form submit via ajax, but I'm hoping I can save some work by just changing where the smaller form displays.

**EDIT 2020-02-05 14:40**

Found a webpage that suggests some possible solutions, but doesn't give much direction on how to implement them. https://discourse.wicg.io/t/position-an-element-relatively-to-another-element-from-anywhere-in-the-dom/968

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [`form` *attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform) to avoid the nesting of `form` elements. You move the controls from the main form outside of that form element, and add the `form` attribute to all of them.

Now you can place the small form at its desired position, without violating the HTML rule that `form` elements should not be nested.

You would still need to apply some CSS on that small form element, so it does not flow to the left. Something like `display: inline-block` or similar could be useful.

Here is the suggested HTML part:

```html
<form id="mainform" action="action1" method="post"></form>
<div>
    Name <input type="text" name="name" form="mainform" value="">
    Job Title <input type="text" name="job_title" form="mainform" value="">
    Cell Number <input type="tel" name="mobile" form="mainform" value="">
        <!-- Smaller form loaded via js -->
        <form id="optin_js_loaded_form">
        </form>
    Favorite Sport <input type="text" name="favorite_sport" form="mainform" value="">
    Hobbies <input type="text" name="hobbies" form="mainform" value="">
    <input type="submit" form="mainform" value="Save">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Very useful! Only problem is some versions of IE and Edge don't support it. https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute.